# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{(2x)^2}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, continuity

I have this question in my book and the answer amounts to $\frac14$. I don't see how, and I think it's an error. Can you confirm it is an error?

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos x}{(2x)^2}$$

I assume it would need to be $\cos^2 x$ instead.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed not correct. Simply use l'Hopital rule allow you to conclude that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{(2x)^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{4x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{8x}=\frac{1}{8}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Knowing $\sin^2 \frac{a}{2} = 2(1-\cos a)$,

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\cos x}{(2x)^2} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}}{(2x)^2} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}}{2x^2} = \frac{1}{8}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (\frac{\sin \frac{x}{2}}{\frac{x}{2}})^2 = \frac{1}{8}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{4x^2}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-1+2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{16(x/2)^2}$$
$$=\lim_{x/2\to0}\frac{2\sin^2{(x/2)}}{16(x/2)^2}$$
$$=\frac18$$

Answer (score 0):

With the power series of $ \cos$:

$\frac{1-\cos(x)}{(2x)^2}=\frac{1}{8}-\frac{x^2}{4*4!}+-... \to \frac{1}{8}$  for $x \to 0$.